# Set command in the middle of do shell script

Tags: applescript

I have been attempting to make a simple application that copies a selected file to a predetermined directory, only the variable does not work when set in a shell script. I was wondering if there is a way to phrase the copy or move command to allow it to take effect. The script is below.

```
set filepath to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Chose your file")
delay
do shell script "cp " & filepath & " ~/Library/Application Support/"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not work because space characters in paths must be escaped, the most reliable way is to use `quoted form of`.

`path to application support folder from user domain` is the relative path to the current user's application support folder.

```
set applicationSupportFolder to POSIX path of (path to application support folder from user domain)
set filepath to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Chose your file")
do shell script "cp " & quoted form of filepath & space & quoted form of applicationSupportFolder
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. This is great and I now have the program working! This was exactly what I needed! Thanks!