# Two file path types in one command?

Tags: applescript

I have been struggling to make a basic program that copies selected files to a predetermined location. However it always ends up with the command having two different path types. is there any way that I can bypass this as it is bugging me and i have finished every other aspect of the program.

```
set targetFolder to (POSIX path of (path to home folder)) & "Library/Application Support/..." as POSIX file

set filepath to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Chose your file")

delay

do shell script "cp " & filepath & space & targetFolder

delay

display dialog "Your file has been moved!"
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [applescript set command in the middle of do shell script?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130717/applescript-set-command-in-the-middle-of-do-shell-script)

Answer (score 0):

It's exactly the same as your [previous](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42130717/applescript-set-command-in-the-middle-of-do-shell-script) question: Didn't you read my answer? You have to use quoted POSIX paths.

```
set applicationSupportFolder to POSIX path of (path to application support folder from user domain)
set filepath to POSIX path of (choose file with prompt "Chose your file")
do shell script "cp " & quoted form of filepath & space & quoted form of applicationSupportFolder
```

And you don't need any delays.